# Module Federation Material shared dependency issue (Nextjs as host, React as Remote)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation, nextjs-dynamic-routing

### App Structure

I'm using Next JS in Host app and React JS in remote app. Both apps are using below library as dependency

#### Note

I'm using ModuleFederationPlugin for both app and not using Next Js Specific module federation plugin

Remote app deps

```js
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
"@mui/styles": "^5.11.2",
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
```

Host app deps

```js
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.103",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.9",
"@mui/styles": "^5.10.9",
```

### Problem Statement

I'm having a problem when trying to share material related module in Host app. When running host app, it shown below error.
I don't want to add `eager: true` in material related dependencies since its ended up creating large initial chunk which I don't want. Also removing material related dependencies from Host app seems not a good idea because then multiple instance warning is showing.

The remote app is also configured as shown [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#uncaught-error-shared-module-is-not-available-for-eager-consumption)

#### Please share some thought on how to share these deps in an optimised way.

Error Screenshot

[image]

Host app shared config (Next JS App)

```
 const dotenvFile = `.env.${process.env.DOTENV_RUNTIME || 'local'}`
require('dotenv').config({ path: dotenvFile })

const deps = require('../../package.json').dependencies

module.exports = {
 distDir: '../../dist/client',
 async rewrites() {
   /*
 This rewrites method is needed to persist route state while using MFE.
 Keep adding base route here when onboarding new MFE App
 */
   return [ ]
 },
 webpack: (config, { webpack, isServer }) => {
   const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container

   if (!isServer) {
     config.plugins.push(
       new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
         resourceRegExp: /urlencoded-body-parser/,
       }),
       new ModuleFederationPlugin({
         name: 'Host ui',
         remotes: {},
         shared: {
           react: {
             eager: true,
             singleton: true,
             requiredVersion: deps.react,
           },
           'react-dom': {
             eager: true,
             singleton: true,
             requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
           },
           '@mui/materia': {
             requiredVersion: deps['@mui/materia'],
             singleton: true,
           },
           '@mui/icons-material': {
             requiredVersion: deps['@mui/icons-material'],
             singleton: true,
           },
           '@mui/styles': {
             requiredVersion: deps['@mui/styles'],
             singleton: true,
           },
           '@emotion/react': {
             requiredVersion: deps['@emotion/react'],
             singleton: true,
           },
         },
       }),
     )
   }

   return config
 },
}
```

Remote app shared config (React JS App)

```
 shared: {
        react: {
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
          singleton: true,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        'react-router': {
          requiredVersion: deps['react-router'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        'react-router-dom': {
          requiredVersion: deps['react-router-dom'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        '@mui/materia': {
          requiredVersion: deps['@mui/materia'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        '@mui/icons-material': {
          requiredVersion: deps['@mui/icons-material'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        '@mui/styles': {
          requiredVersion: deps['@mui/styles'],
          singleton: true,
        },
        '@emotion/react': {
          requiredVersion: deps['@emotion/react'],
          singleton: true,
        },
      },
```

Github Issue link - https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/2740

I have tried adding `eager:true` in Host app but its making initial chunk 5 MB which is not expected. My expectation is my configuration works without adding `eager` key in any app.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?, I'm having exactly the same problem